# Do node.js binaries exist for the ARMv7 hard-float processor architecture?

Tags: python, node.js, arm, embedded-linux

Do Node.js binaries exist for the ARMv7 hard float instruction set?  This is a popular platform due to Raspberry Pi, but I'm using an extremely stripped down version of embedded linux running on a hardware evaluation board.  Native compilation is not possible due to Node's Python dependencies during compilation.  Some possibly helpful information is as follows:

Processor: [i.MX537](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX537)

Evaluation board: http://www.tq-group.com/en/products/industry-pcs/prod/embedded-modul-tqma53/extb/Main/productdetail/

Another interesting problem/challenge is the embedded linux that comes as a base support package for the hardware doesn't have a typical package manager.  It uses opkg, and I'm unable to leverage any of the Raspberry Pi or Arch Linux packages.

I'm interested in node binaries because I'm trying to fast-track an application demo and our hardware design will require a kernel rebuild anyhow, so I don't want to spend lots of time setting up cross-compilation toolchains if any stable binaries exist.

Comment: You could try cross-compiling, like as described here: http://www.wigwag.com/devblog/cross-compile-node-js-for-arm/   Caveat Emptor...

Comment: there is an arm-pi binary here http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.16/node-v0.10.16-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

While I've not seen raw binaries for Node (I've used [Nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)'s packages before), [io.js](https://iojs.org) provides binaries for armv7. [Direct link](https://iojs.org/dist/v1.4.3/iojs-v1.4.3-linux-armv7l.tar.xz) to the io.js 1.4.3 armv7 release.